# In ExtJs, can you slide a panel over?

Tags: extjs

When I expand a collapsible panel within a layout it compresses the content of the panel next to it.  I'd like instead to shift the content of the panel over so it is as if the collapsible panel is moving the content of that panel over to make room for it when it expands.  I'm not looking for any animation effects, just the structural behavior of the content shifting.  This demo (using jquery) illustrates the behavior I'm trying to achieve.  http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-pageslide/ Can I do this in Ext?

Comment: I think you forgot to post a link for the jQuery demo.

Answer (score 0):

More info is in the ExtJs Forums: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?43120-Ext.layout.SlideLayout-Sliding-Card-Layout-(Shift-Fx)/